# ZXingScannerView Not run on Xiaomi device

Tags: android-intent, background, zxing, xiaomi

Look, I have another problem. I am using the ZXing scanner in Android Tudio. It works, but with Xiaomi, it only works with the qr camera open.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_q_r_scann);

    ViewGroup contentFrame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
    contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        disconnect = extras.getString("disconnect");
    }

    notifm = (NotificationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifm.cancelAll();

    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    if(latitud == null){
        latitud = preferences.getString("coorlat","");
        longitud = preferences.getString("coorlong","");
    }
}
```

It is accessed from a Intent from service background:

```
Intent content = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainQRScann.class);
            content.putExtra("disconnect", ident);
            content.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            activityF.startActivity(content);
            new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            diafinal.dismiss();
                        }
                    }, 650);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem for Xiaomi devices only, I found out that while ZXing doesn't work in debug, when you generate an APK, move to the device and install it manually, the scanner works as intended.

Looks like a problem related to the debug environment, that should not appear when releasing your app.

---

Source:

- Debugged on Virtual device and virtual camera: Worked
- Debugged on S10+: Worked
- Debugged on Redmi Note 8T: Nope
- Debugged on Redmi Note 5: Nope
- Generated APK, moved to 8T, installed (updated old debug apk): Worked

Comment: Ok, i will try it.